# Eclipse: Debug buttons are disabled

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse Mars on Mac, and my Debug buttons are disabled(not clickable). I am in the correct perspective, selected correct thread.

Already tried "Show Debug Toolbar" option and  "Reset Perspective".

When I try to customize, Debug option is enabled.
It is stopping at breakpoints, just resume,stop options are not coming.

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Is your debug session running?Are you debugging Java code or C/C++ code?

Comment: Restart eclipse and try again

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this?